# Can someone help me identify the fonts highlighted within the red boxes?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What font was used within the red highlighted areas of the included image of KPM 1001 The Mood Modern?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The majority of the disk is [Gill Sans](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-sans/) of different versions.  Since it is from 1966 I would guess that it is using an old version that has since been modified.  There are also many different versions of "Gill Sans" but the original seems to be the closest.  That number 1 I have run into before and never did manage to find a match for it.  But all the other numbers match.

The printing method for this disk distorts some of the details of the fonts like the K and the R.

[image: Gill Sans Display Bold]

[image: Gill Sans Medium]

**EDIT**

I found this bit on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans) about Gill Sans

**Monotype developed a set of alternate characters** for Gill Sans to cater for differing tastes and national printing styles of different countries. These include Futura-inspired designs of "N", "M", "R", "a", "g", "t" and others, a four-terminal "W" in the French renaissance style, a tighter "R", a "Q" in the nineteenth-century style with a tail that looped upwards (similar to that on Century among others, and preferred by the LNER), oblique designs as opposed to the standard true italic, a more curving, true-italic "e" and several alternative numerals. **In particular, in the standard designs for Gill Sans the numeral "1", upper-case "i" and lower-case "L" are all a simple vertical line, so an alternate "1" with a serif was sold for number-heavy situations where this could otherwise cause confusion, such as on price-lists.** (Not all timetables used it: for example, the L.N.E.R. preferred the simple version.) Some early versions of Gill Sans also had features later abandoned, such as an unusual "7" matching the curve of the "9", a "5" pushing forwards, and a lower-case letter-height "0".

Comment: Both Gill Sans and Granby are similar, but the narrow R is a feature of Granby, not Gill Sans. The leg on Gill Sans sticks out proportionally slightly further and the counter inside the R is smaller.

Comment: The R is slightly closer on Granby, but for the slight difference of the leg on the R, the majority of the Gill Sans Display letters are a better match.  I updated your answer to include a screenshot of Granby.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly seems to be Granby. ℗ seems to be something else, maybe Times New Roman. The numbers seem to be Futura, though. Likely this is Granby Regular, but it looks bolder than the digital version because of the ink spread when it was letterpress printed. This can't be Granby Bold because that has a different R where the right-hand leg connects to the vertical stroke not the horizontal. Gotham is a digital font that looks quite similar to this. The words 'Johnny Hawksworth' are in Gill Sans.

If it matters, the text reversed from green is Univers and 'kpm' is probably a custom wordmark.

[image: Granby Fonts]